# Finding boundary co-ordinates from given set of point co-ordinates?

Tags: algorithm, polygon-creation, vertices, convex-hull

Given a set of coordinates, How do we find the boundary coordinates.
[image: set of coordinates]
<== **Figure 1**
Given the coordinates in the above set, How can I get the coordinates on the red boundary. Boundary is the polygon which is formed by the input coordinates for vertices, in such a way that it maximizes the area.

I am working on an app which searches properties within 'x' miles of a *city*. What I have is:

1. Coordinates of all the properties.
2. A set of coordinates for each city (I have one coordinate for each zip. And since most cities have more than one zip, Every city has a set of coordinates)

The reason I am asking for the *maximum area* is so that I don't come up with a polygon like the one below:

[image: crooked polygon]  <== **Figure 2**

What I need is the *algorithm* to come up with the set of coordinates for the boundary. An algorithm which will allow me to come up with boundary coordinates for **Figure 1**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concave Hull: Definition, Algorithms and Practical Solutions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions)

Comment: No, not duplicate, this is convex hull, not concave

Comment: Are you looking for code, theoretical references, or solutions in specific existing software environments?

Comment: What software / platform are you wiling to use for that?

Comment: @Khaja No, you don't want to maximize the area, you want to *minimize* it among all *convex* polygons containing the points.  (The only way to maximize the area is to use the entire world as the containing polygon.)

Comment: Re: the votes to close.  This question would duplicate http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-i-create-a-convex-hull-in-arcgis only if the desired solution is in ArcGIS.  Otherwise there is no valid reason to close it.

Comment: The question linked to by @iant has a lot of pointers, Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Khaja Re the edit (Figure 2): *Convexity* is the key property here, not area.  However, it is not clear what either of these has to do with *proximity,* which is what seems to be your ultimate interest.  Are you looking for a data structure that makes proximity searches more efficient?

Comment: @radek This is being used in an asp.net mvc web application, and I am planning to do this computation on our database (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: @WolfOdrade I wanted an algorithm, but it seems like this is a common problem and there are lots of pre-built functions in SQL Server to help with this. This is one => http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/archive/2010/02/08/creating-convex-hull-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @whuber Yeah, now I see what you mean, I want a convex polygon with the minimal area. My ultimate goal is to do a proximity search. The way we want our proximity search to work is: In a given city (convex hull), if we search for homes (each home has a coordinate) within "x" miles, it should give me all the *homes* which are either *inside the convex hull* **or** *are at an orthogonal distance of less than "x" miles*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many algorithms to solve this problem ([Wikipedia "Convex_hull_algorithms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms)):

- **Gift wrapping aka Jarvis march — O(nh):** One of the simplest algorithms. It has O(nh) time complexity, where n is the number of points in the set, and h is the number of points in the hull. In the worst case the complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- **Graham scan — O(n log n):** Slightly more sophisticated, but much more efficient algorithm. If the points are already sorted by one of the coordinates or by the angle to a fixed vector, then the algorithm takes O(n) time. [[pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan#Pseudocode)]
- **QuickHull:** Like the quicksort algorithm, it has the expected time complexity of O(n log n), but may degenerate to O(nh) = O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case. [[illustrated description](https://web.archive.org/web/20120507000532/http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/0040_quickhull_introduction_and_php_implementation.html)]
- **Divide and conquer — O(n log n):** This algorithm is also applicable to the three dimensional case.
- **Monotone chain — O(n log n):** A variant of Graham scan which sorts the points lexicographically by their coordinates. When the input is already sorted, the algorithm takes O(n) time.
- **Incremental convex hull algorithm — O(n log n)**
- **Marriage-before-conquest — O(n log h):** Optimal output-sensitive algorithm.
- **Chan's algorithm — O(n log h):** Simpler optimal output-sensitive algorithm .

Comment: Thank you for listing these @underdark ... which one is your pick?

Answer (score 8):

1. Convex Hull in [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.hull.html)
2. Convex Hull in [Qgis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) Vector Tools (very easy to use):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the Convex hull. In PostGIS there is a function (actually GEOS) that gives you the Convex hull, [ST_ConvexHull(geometry)](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_ConvexHull.html).

At wikipedia there is a lot of info about concave hulls.

Answer (score 3):

Hawth's Tools for ArcGIS has this [functionality](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/createmcp.php). Plus a [script](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=AA23C5C6-1422-2418-8811-1365253A756A) for ArcInfo 10.

There is also convex hull tool in [QuantumGIS](http://qgis.org/) via [ftools plugin](http://www.ftools.ca/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an algorithm to do this (rather than packages that can do it) then I'd think you would need to triangulate the data; or basically define a line from each point to every other point. Then, starting at (say) the point with the highest Y value, trace a route around the outside following the connected line with the smallest exterior angle/bearing.

You would be able to speed up the tracing by throwing away intersecting lines first. The external boundary won't have intersections.

btw - FME will do this too with the ConvexHullAccumulator or ConvexHullReplacer transformers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in looking at an existing algorithm implemented in code, NetTopologySuite has an algorithm to do this

See [ConvexHull.cs](https://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/source/browse/trunk/NetTopologySuite/Algorithm/ConvexHull.cs?r=821)

Incidentally NTS and a bunch of other libraries are wrapped up in a cool project called DotSpatial, found [here](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/)