# Extracting points bordering shape extent

Tags: arcgis-9.3, export, 3d-analyst, select-by-location, convex-hull

I'm using ArcGIS 9.31.

I have a set of points as elevation and in order to get a soft clip area for the TIN, I would like to extract only all the points bordering the extent of this shape, or to get a shape deliminating the extent of the set of points. I don't have any other data than this point shape. Is there a way to select them?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [**How do I create a convex hull in ArcGIS?**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-i-create-a-convex-hull-in-arcgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to generate a Convex Hull for which options are described **[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-i-create-a-convex-hull-in-arcgis)**.

There is also some discussion about generating Concave Hulls and a few tools you may be able to try **[here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/49630-how-to-automatically-%E2%80%9Cdraw%E2%80%9D-a-polygon-around-points-that-have-similar-value)**.

Comment: Thanks I haven't seen your reply before. This si what I finally tried and then reshape the result.