# Location Allocation (lines) to Polygon map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, location-allocation

I have a solved "Location-Allocation" Analysis, providing a map result like [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/chssweb/images/6697/oversized/koizumi-map-2.jpg?1319207188).

What methods do I have, to help transform this into a segmented polygon areas?  Current doing it by hand, but have the entire nation to do!

Comment: What do you mean by a segmented polygon area, can you show us an example?

Answer (score 2):

If I follow your question correctly (you want unique polygons for each transit zone) and assuming you have the proper license, what you want is to use the tool "Minimum Bounding Geometry" this will create a feature class containing polygons which represent a specified minimum bounding geometry enclosing each input feature or each group of input features.  You will want to choose convex hull

You can build this into a model to iterate through all your groups of points.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=191468

[Creating convex hull in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-i-create-a-convex-hull-in-arcgis-desktop)