# Point to Polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, point, excel

I am a city planner doing a GIS parcel layer update for our City's GIS system. I have uploaded our data from Microsoft Excel into ArcMap as a point file.

I need to get it into a polygon file and I am having quite a bit of trouble. Every join or tool that I know of has not worked. We have ArcMap 10.2 Standard. Is there an equivalent of Feature to Polygon that anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use minimum bounding boxes but with standard you are limited to rectangle which will produce a lot of overlap. Convex hulls are preferable but you don't have the license for it. You can download QGIS for free and export your point features as a shapefile and use their convex hull geoprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site and download the free tools:  http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm

Also have a look at this question and it's answers for other options:  [Creating convex hull in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/creating-convex-hull-in-arcgis-desktop)

As ShaunO suggested, you need to create convex hulls around your points.