# Automatically digitize polygons by most outlying points within cluster in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convex-hull

I'm looking for a tool or script that will allow me to automate the digitization of polygons by the most outlying points in a cluster of points with the same key attribute. Below is a sample image displaying this done manually.

[image]

Selected points are all with the same ID of "MD_1001". I have drawn a polygon around these points, and angled the polygon via the most outlying points in the cluster.

I have thousands of these clusters to digitize polygons over, and need some sort of tool or script to get this done quickly. I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: You want to create a bunch of Convex Hulls. See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/creating-convex-hull-in-arcgis-desktop

Comment: [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Minimum_Bounding_Geometry/00170000003q000000/) includes Convex Hull (needs Advanced license I believe), or look at the [Geometry class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Geometry/018z00000070000000/) in arcpy which also offers Convex Hull - see this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/207683/64785 from the Q&A @DanC links to above

Comment: @Midavalo I thought about marking this as duplicate, but it seemed to me that the phrasing of the question here ("most outlying points..") might help other people find the solution if they don't know to look for the term Convex Hull.

Comment: @DanC That's what the duplicate flag will do - if a user finds this post it links back to the duplicate Q&A.  Your comment indicates that they want to create Convex Hulls

Comment: @Midavalo I'm embarassed to say I didn't know that about duplicates! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you both, Minimum Bounding Geometry did the trick!