# Removing triangles that fall into the concave but exterior part of polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin

I have created a TIN for all the polygons in a block and then converted it to a feature layer in order to be able to delete the triangles that fall in the polygons. Now I want to remove triangles that fall into the concave but exterior part of polygons. But I don't know how to do it in ArcGIS. This condition makes triangles with all three vertices located on the same object to be removed from consideration.  The screenshot of part of my data is as the first picture. And I want to remove exterior white triangle as shown in the second picture. And My final purpose is to form a skeleton graph for each street block, like the third picture. In other words, I want to implement Thiessen polygon for polygons instead of points but I don't know how to do it. If I would be able to implement Thiessen polygon for polygon objects, it would be used instead.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thiessen polygons around polygons?   Use the Euclidean Allocation tool in ArcToolbox-Spatial Analyst Tools-Distance-Euclidean Allocation.  Convert the resulting raster to polygons if necessary.

Comment: Can you delete the Polygons that have a Vertex count of 3?

Comment: Select ones that are completely inside  and delete or switch selection and delete.

Comment: @GBG I tried the way you stated but the results are not satisfactory as some of the Thiessen polygons around polygons intersect with polygon boundary

Comment: @klewis I don't understand what you mean. All the triangles have vertex count of 3.

Comment: @FelixIP I have deleted the ones that are completely inside. But I don't know how to remove triangles that fall into the concave but exterior part of the polygons.

Comment: Convert polygons into concavehulls, check where the majority of their area is.

Comment: @parastoo What output cell size are you using with te Euclidean Allocation too/?  Maybe the cell size is larger that the gaps between buildings?  Maybe you are inputting or outputting non-projected data and that is messing up the analysis?

Comment: @GBG I set the pixel size to 1. the results improved a lot but again there are some Thiessen polygons that intersect with polygon boundary.

Comment: @parastoo Is the pixel size unit of measure larger than the distance between some of the buildings?  One what?  One kilometer pixel?

Comment: @GBG I have not measured all the distances among polygons, is it necessary? I had set the pixel size to one meter but the problem occurs for some irregular polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the convex hull of the polygons, then select by location the triangles that "are within" the convex hull and remove them. In order to create convex hull, you can use the minimum bounding geometry tool (see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8/creating-convex-hull-in-arcgis-desktop) for more details).

As a remark, a quick and dirty method to achieve your "thiessen polygons" for polygons is to 1) densify the polygons with a distance smaller than the distance between two polygons, 2) convert polygon vertices to points, 3) create thiessen polygons for points and 4) dissolve based on the attributes of the original ID of the polygons. But, this is not an exact solution.

[image]